# My div shows for a second despite display: none and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

first maybe I'll show you my js
http://jsfiddle.net/nuYT3/

Well problem is that #lightbox shows for a half a second before rest of the page loads. I've thought if I place display: none at it, it won't show at all. But that method doesn't work. :( What's wrong with my js that it shows (but only sometimes) for just a second?

```
    jQuery('#tellfriend_lightbox, #tellfriend_thanks').hide();
```

Something wrong with that?

thanks.

Comment: some HTML might help. :)

Comment: Your fiddle has no HTML, no CSS and doesn't even work because it doesn't include jQuery. Nobody is going to be able to help you if they don't know what you are actually doing.

Comment: Why don't you hide it using CSS? Maybe combine it with `<noscript>` tag for user with javascript disabled if it needs to be displayed in this case.

Comment: Have you applied `display:none` to `#tellfriend_lightbox, #tellfriend_thanks` or something else? Because it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see your code is inside $(document).ready(), which means it's executed when document is ready.

The problem with this is that before document is ready there is a delay.

To avoid these I'd suggest to add a css style to that ids, and to show the div or not in JS.

CSS

```
<style>
#tellfriend_lightbox, #tellfriend_thanks {
   display: none;
}
</style>
```

And then when you need to show them up just call

```
jQuery('#tellfriend_lightbox, #tellfriend_thanks').show();
```